# Python Flask application duplicate HTTP requests

Tags: python, html, http, flask, request

I am working on a Flask web application, and encountering an issue concerning duplicate HTTP requests.

Every time a request is made, it is sent twice (for GET requests and POST requests as well), as can be seen on the screenshot below. I am running the application in production environment and with debug mode being "off".

How could I find out why the requests are being sent twice ?

**EDIT:**

The view functions are indeed being called twice every time a request is made. Any ideas ?

```
from flask import render_template


@product.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def index():
    print('Request to index.')
    products = Product.query.all()
    return render_template('product/index.html', products=products)
```

[image: Duplicate HTTP GET request]

Comment: Are they sent twice or logged twice?

Comment: Hello Klaus, thanks for your feedback. How could I make sure if they are indeed sent twice or just being logged twice ?

Comment: Inspect the traffic with a tool like tcpdump, wireshark or tshark.

Comment: Try to check the number of requests sent by inspecting the traffic through your browser's network console and share the response here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome sends an extra GET request for a favicon. Add this to the head of your html to stop this request

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/x-icon;," type="image/x-icon">
```